# Reduce flicker when using CPaintDC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-2010

I need to make an interactive graph using MFC

It will be sort of like an equalizer control, where the user should be able to click on a point on the equalizer drag it to change it's y axis value

I am also just starting to learn MFC

Upto this point I have used `CPaintDC` in the `OnPaint()` function to draw the graph in a dialog box. For now the graph is very simple, with rectangle boarder, filled with white colour, and 4 points on the graph. I use `OnMouseMove()` function to know if the cursor is inside the graph area and `OnLButtonDown()` function to know where the user has clicked. If the user has clicked at a position which implies I want to change the y axis value of the graph point at that location, I repaint the figure using `Invalidate()` and calling `OnPaint()` inside `OnLButtonDown()`. However, every time the graph has to update, I can see a flicker. it is not a problem now, but I will need to extend this graph so that it has at least 64 changeable points, with the ability to change the y axis value for a point by dragging instead of just clicking where I want it to go. Will the flickering problem increase as I increase the number of points and the complexity of the appearance of the graph? The graph will need to have axes, gridlines, labels, etc later on. Is the flickering something I should be concerned about? Is there any way I can prevent it?

----UPDATE ----
This is how I updated my OnPaint() function according to how I understood CodeDreamer's suggestion

```
void Cgraph_on_dlgboxDlg::OnPaint()
{
     CPaintDC dc_blt(this);
     CDC dc;
     CBitmap bmpDC;

     CRect rcClient;
     GetClientRect(rcClient);

    if (IsIconic())
    {
        // CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }

     dc.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
     bmpDC.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc, theGraph.width,theGraph.height );
     dc.SelectObject(&bmpDC);

    CPen pen;
    COLORREF pencolour = RGB(0, 0, 0);
    COLORREF brushcolour = RGB(0, 0, 255);
    COLORREF graphColour = RGB(0, 0, 150);

    // Draw boarder
    pen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, pencolour);
    // CBrush brush(HS_CROSS, brushcolour);
    dc.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    dc.SetMapMode(MM_TEXT);
    dc.SetViewportOrg(theGraph.x1, theGraph.y1);
     dc.SelectObject(&pen);

    // Draw graph boundary
    CPoint point1(0,0);
    point1.x = 0;
    point1.y = 0;
    CPoint point2(0,0);
    point2.x = point1.x + theGraph.width;
    point2.y = point1.y + theGraph.height;
    dc.Rectangle(CRect(point1, point2));
    pen.DeleteObject();

    // Draw Horizontal at 0
    pen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, pencolour);
    dc.SelectObject(&pen);
    dc.MoveTo(0, theGraph.height - ORG_DIST_FROM_BOTTOM);
    dc.LineTo(theGraph.width, theGraph.height - ORG_DIST_FROM_BOTTOM);
    pen.DeleteObject();

    dc.SetViewportOrg(theGraph.x1, theGraph.y1 + theGraph.height - ORG_DIST_FROM_BOTTOM); // dc.SetViewportOrg() always works relative to the clinet origin

    // Draw graph line
    pen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, graphColour);
    dc.SelectObject(&pen);
    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_OF_SECTIONS_IN_GRAPH; i++){
        dc.MoveTo(graphSamplePoints[i].x, graphSamplePoints[i].y);
        dc.LineTo(graphSamplePoints[i+1].x, graphSamplePoints[i+1].y);
    }

    // draw circles at graph sample points
    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_OF_POINTS_IN_GRAPH; i++){
        CIRCLE(dc, graphSamplePoints[i].x, graphSamplePoints[i].y, GRP_SMP_RAD);        
    }

    // dc_blt.BitBlt(0,0,rcClient.Width(), rcClient.Height(), &dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    dc_blt.BitBlt(theGraph.x1,theGraph.y1,theGraph.width, theGraph.height, &dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

}
```

I will need to change the origins of the viewport a number of times and my guess is that this could be one of the reasons for the error. Any suggestions will be welcome.
This is what my output look like without double buffering
[image]
This is what it looks like with my attempt at double buffering

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flicker does not reduce after double buffering in MFC CPaintDC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483147/flicker-does-not-reduce-after-double-buffering-in-mfc-cpaintdc)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, a general solution is 'double buffering'. 
The principle is that it creates a compatible memory dc for drawing in advance, and when drawing is ended, it outputs on screen dc.

A code sample is below.

```
//in OnPaint() function
CPaintDC dc(this);    
CDC dcMem;
CBitmap bmpDC;

CRect rcClient;
GetClientRect(&rcClient);

dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
bmpDC.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, rcClient.Width(), rcClient.Height());
dcMem.SelectObject(&bmpDC);

CRect rect(0, 0, 100, 200);
dcMem.Rectangle(rect);

dc.BitBlt(0, 0, rcClient.Width(), rcClient.Height(), &dcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

A couple of references are below.

[introduction](http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/f0d22ad178899ea6.htm)

[another reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5865/Double-Buffered-DC-Class)

I hope this will help you a little.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What is pDC in this sample? MSDN says it should be CDC* . Is it a global variable or should be declared inside OnPaint?

Comment: If I understood correctly, whatever I am drawing on the screen at the moment using a `CPaintDC` object, I should do the same things using a `CDC` object, and instead of drawing onto the screen, I should draw onto a `CBitmap` using the `CDC` object, then use a `CPaintDC` object just to copy this `CBitmap` back onto the screen. Is this correct or did I miss something here?

Comment: 1) pDC : It's my mistake. You just use current dc. Here is dc, so that 'dcMem.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);' is exact code. I'm sorry. 2) You are understanding exactly about double buffering. My English is not good.. Thank you.

Comment: so the actual graphic that I am painting is the rectangle at (0,0,100,200), but BitBlt will be repainting the whole client area? Or should I just include the area of my graph as the 1st four arguments of BitBlt? Also what are the third and second from last arguments (the two 0s)? Are logical co-ordinates the same as the client area co-ordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [CMemDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc308997%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) MFC class.

In your OnPaintFunction you would have this:

```
  CPaintDC   DC(this);
  CMemDC mDC(&DC, this);
  // now use mDC instead of DC
```

Also look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33/Flicker-Free-Drawing-In-MFC) fore more samples and explanations.

Comment: what is pDC in this case? Is it also CDC *pDC?

Comment: did you mean use mDC for all the CPaintDC variables that I had been using? other CDC based function such as Rectangle() aren't working anymore if I replace CPaintDC object with CMemDC object

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the answer, there is no more pDC. And also look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33/Flicker-Free-Drawing-In-MFC

Comment: @user13267, didn't this approach solved your case?? Did it gave you any sorta improvement?