# Flicker does not reduce after double buffering in MFC CPaintDC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-2010

I am trying to make an interactive graph using MFC where the y axis of a sample point in the graph can be changed using mouse click. I implemented double buffering using this tutorial
[enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2432/Do-a-flicker-free-drawing-using-MFC-methods). I should also point out that I need to change the origins of the viewport from time to time for my program. However, when I click on the graph for the sample point to be updated, I can still see it flicker. It's not an inconvenience, but I need to extend this graph to include lots of sample points and other features such as gridlines, axes, labels, boundary areas, etc and I am worried that the flickering might become a problem for me in the future as the size of this project grows. Implementing double buffering did not seem to make any changes to the output. Moreover, now that I have implemented double buffering, the program seems to stop in the middle of execution (when I am running it in Debug mode in Visual Studio) with this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0xffffff3a in graph_on_dlgbox.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffff3a.
```

I am still not sure what causes it to appear, but seems to happen if I start randomly clicking around the graph area rapidly. Since I have not seen this error (yet) in my code that does not use double buffering, I am assuming it has something to do with the double buffering code, but I am not sure.
Anyway I would like to tackle this one problem at a time, and the first problem is the flicker. Here is my code without double buffering:

```
void Cgraph_on_dlgboxDlg::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        // CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }

    CPen pen;
    COLORREF pencolour = RGB(0, 0, 0);
    COLORREF brushcolour = RGB(0, 0, 255);
    COLORREF graphColour = RGB(0, 0, 150);

    // Draw boarder
    pen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, pencolour);
    // CBrush brush(HS_CROSS, brushcolour);
    dc.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    dc.SetMapMode(MM_TEXT);
    dc.SetViewportOrg(theGraph.x1, theGraph.y1);
    // Dc.SetViewportExt(theGraph.width, theGraph.height);
     dc.SelectObject(&pen);
    // dc.SelectObject(&brush);

    // Draw graph boundary
    CPoint point1(0,0);
    point1.x = 0;
    point1.y = 0;
    CPoint point2(0,0);
    point2.x = point1.x + theGraph.width;
    point2.y = point1.y + theGraph.height;
    dc.Rectangle(CRect(point1, point2));
    pen.DeleteObject();

    // Draw Horizontal at 0
    pen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, pencolour);
    dc.SelectObject(&pen);
    dc.MoveTo(0, theGraph.height - ORG_DIST_FROM_BOTTOM);
    dc.LineTo(theGraph.width, theGraph.height - ORG_DIST_FROM_BOTTOM);
    pen.DeleteObject();

    // Shift overall graph origin from top left corner to beginning of this horizontal line
    dc.SetViewportOrg(theGraph.x1, theGraph.y1 + theGraph.height - ORG_DIST_FROM_BOTTOM); // dc.SetViewportOrg() always works relative to the clinet origin

    // Draw graph line
    pen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, graphColour);
    dc.SelectObject(&pen);
    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_OF_SECTIONS_IN_GRAPH; i++){
        dc.MoveTo(graphSamplePoints[i].x, graphSamplePoints[i].y);
        dc.LineTo(graphSamplePoints[i+1].x, graphSamplePoints[i+1].y);
    }

    // draw circles at graph sample points
    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_OF_POINTS_IN_GRAPH; i++){
        CIRCLE(dc, graphSamplePoints[i].x, graphSamplePoints[i].y, GRP_SMP_RAD);        
    }
}
```

and here is the modified version with double buffering:

```
void Cgraph_on_dlgboxDlg::OnPaint()
{

    // /*****
    CPaintDC dc_blt(this);
    CDC dc;
    CBitmap bmpDC;
    // CRect rcClient;
    // GetClientRect(rcClient);

    if (IsIconic())
    {
        // CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }

    dc.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc_blt);
    // bmpDC.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc_blt, rcClient.Width(),rcClient.Height());
    bmpDC.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc_blt, theGraph.width,theGraph.height );
    dc.SelectObject(&bmpDC);

    // ----------- After this point, do all operations considering (0,0) to be the origin of the bitmap
    // consider bitmap coordinates a device coordinates for Viewport operations

    CPen pen;
    COLORREF pencolour = RGB(0, 0, 0);
    COLORREF brushcolour = RGB(0, 0, 255);
    COLORREF graphColour = RGB(0, 0, 150);

    // Draw boarder
    pen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, pencolour);
    // CBrush brush(HS_CROSS, brushcolour);
    dc.SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
    dc.SetMapMode(MM_TEXT);
    // dc.SetViewportOrg(theGraph.x1, theGraph.y1);
    // dc.SetViewportExt(theGraph.width, theGraph.height);
     dc.SelectObject(&pen);
    // dc.SelectObject(&brush);

    // Draw graph boundary
    CPoint point1(0,0);
    point1.x = 0;
    point1.y = 0;
    CPoint point2(0,0);
    point2.x = point1.x + theGraph.width;
    point2.y = point1.y + theGraph.height;
    dc.Rectangle(CRect(point1, point2));
    pen.DeleteObject();

    // Draw Horizontal at 0
    pen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, pencolour);
    dc.SelectObject(&pen);
    dc.MoveTo(0, theGraph.height - ORG_DIST_FROM_BOTTOM);
    dc.LineTo(theGraph.width, theGraph.height - ORG_DIST_FROM_BOTTOM);
    pen.DeleteObject();

    // Shift overall graph origin from top left corner to beginning of this horizontal line
    // dc.SetViewportOrg(theGraph.x1, theGraph.y1 + theGraph.height - ORG_DIST_FROM_BOTTOM); // dc.SetViewportOrg() always works relative to the client area origin
    // New origin defined in terms of the Bitmap's origin
    dc.SetViewportOrg(0, theGraph.height - ORG_DIST_FROM_BOTTOM);

    // Draw graph line
    pen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, graphColour);
    dc.SelectObject(&pen);
    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_OF_SECTIONS_IN_GRAPH; i++){
        dc.MoveTo(graphSamplePoints[i].x, graphSamplePoints[i].y);
        dc.LineTo(graphSamplePoints[i+1].x, graphSamplePoints[i+1].y);
    }

    // draw circles at graph sample points
    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_OF_POINTS_IN_GRAPH; i++){
        CIRCLE(dc, graphSamplePoints[i].x, graphSamplePoints[i].y, GRP_SMP_RAD);        
    }

    dc.SetViewportOrg(0, 0);
    // dc_blt.BitBlt(rcClient.left+100,rcClient.top+50,rcClient.Width(), rcClient.Height(), &dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    // dc_blt.BitBlt(0,0,rcClient.Width(), rcClient.Height(), &dc, theGraph.x1, theGraph.y1, SRCCOPY);

    dc_blt.BitBlt(theGraph.x1,theGraph.y1, theGraph.width, theGraph.height, &dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    // --- Bring the bitmap to this particular location on screen specified by (theGraph.x1,theGraph.y1, theGraph.width, theGraph.height)

    // dc_blt.BitBlt(0,0,theGraph.width, theGraph.height, &dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    // dc_blt.BitBlt(theGraph.x1,theGraph.y1,theGraph.width, theGraph.height, &dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    // *****/

     m_bMyDraw = FALSE;
}
```

Here is a sample screenshot of the output:
[image]

The y axis values of the sample points on the graph can be changed by clicking, and the program redraws the graph after every click by calling `InvalidateRect()` with the area of the graph as the rectangle to be repainted.
[image]
The coordinates of the sample points are stored in a array of CPoint objects, and it's members are updated every time the graph is clicked at the appropriate area. The graph then repaints, due to the call to `InvalidateRect()`, but with a flicker; unless of course, the program crashes in debug mode with this error:
[image]

How do I remove the flickering?

---- UPDATE ----

```
BOOL Cgraph_on_dlgboxDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    if ( m_bMyDraw )
        return TRUE;
    else
        return CDialogEx::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC);
}
```

This function has been made this way since it was done like this in the tutorial I mentioned earlier
------ UPDATE 2 ----------
If I just put return TRUE; in the body of the above function, the flicker seems to vanish, but now the output looks like this 
[image]
The dialog box background seems to have taken the contents of my Visual Studio window. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

You're close!  The idea of double buffering is to paint every pixel in your window exactly once.  If it is painted zero times, artifacts like Visual Studio remain.  And if it is painted a first time, and then painted again with a different color, you will see flicker.  So, to make sure every pixel is painted, create your compatible dc the full width and height of the window so that when it is copied to the `CPaintDC`, it covers the entire area and not just `theGraph`. Keep returning `TRUE` in `OnEraseBkgnd`, so that the pixels are not first painted in `OnEraseBkgnd`, and then again in `OnPaint`.

Answer (score 2):

Two things :

1. Have you made sure OnEraseBkgnd() just returns TRUE and doesn't call the base class to erase the view?
2. You don't need to do all that drawing for the double buffering in OnPaint(). All you need to do in the OnPaint() is the BitBlt. You can do the drawing to the memory bitmap in a UpdateRect() function which gets called whenever you need to update the screen, which then calls InvalidateRect() to update the screen. I've posted some code about a flicker-free double buffering method I've used many times [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840464/gdi-acceleration-in-windows-7-drawing-to-memory-bitmap/10841445#10841445) which might help.

Comment: I have included my OnEraseBkgnd() in my question. Did you mean that it's function body should just have return TRUE;?

Comment: I am sorry but I did not understand the part about drawing to the memory bitmap in a UpdateRect() function. What is the UpdateRect()? Isn't OnPaint() the function that gets called automatically whenever I need to update the screen? I am drawing this on a non-resizable dialog box so I just need to worry about the cases of other overlapping windows and the parent dialog box being minimized.

Comment: Also, please let me know if I am wrong, but putting all those code for drawing in OnPaint() should not be a cause for flicker should it? Because they are still only drawing into the memDC and not the screen

Comment: Also, just fr reference, I have called `InvalidateRect()` inside the 'OnLButtonDown()' of the dialog box

Comment: Yes, just return TRUE in OnEraseBkgnd(). Don't call the base class. If you're calling the base class, this is probably the cause of your flicker.

Comment: Just seen your second update. The reason you're seeing your VS contents is because you're not drawing the whole window in OnPaint(). You need to create a background bitmap that's the size of the whole client area and fill it with a colour (or whatever), even though you're only interested in your graph area.

Answer (score 2):

The way that flicker prevention work is that first you return TRUE from OnEraseBkgnd to suppress the default erase. But then your OnPaint code must include a full erase of the window. You don't do that so you get the background image of your source code or whatever was there before. So add a FillSolidRect call to your OnPaint to clear the window.

Your creation of a CPaintDC before calling CDialogEx::OnPaint destroys the dialog's ability to properly paint itself, since that function also creates a CPaintDC. But only one call to CPaintDC is permitted for each paint message. To avoid this problem you need a completely different approach. The dialog should have a picture control on it (a CStatic), and you should paint your graph in a class you derive from CStatic.

Comment: Or don't use a `CPaintDC` but a regular `CDC` instead.

Comment: @NikBougalis : did you mean I need to have two CDC's in the above code? The CPaintDC above is only used to BitBlt the bitmap onto the dialog box window, while I am drawing in the CDC (at least that's what I thought I had been doing)            Scott: I had already tried painting into a class derived from a CStatic control but I ran in to other problems so I am using this approach now. Do you think deriving from a CStatic and painting on it is the only way to remove flickering, or is there any way I can make this current approach work as well?